# nodejs process keeps respawning

Tags: node.js, wiki.js

I can no longer access my node.js application. I see thee following behaviours.

1> netstat shows the server listening on the port I expect it to.

2> tcpdump shows traffic from my laptop on the server when I attempt to open the page.

3> When I try to kill the node process with `kill -9` or `pkill node` nothing happens.

I see the pid for the node process is changing continuously as if it was constantly being restarted. I see posts similar to this but none of them have definitive answers.

I have stopped and started the node site as we all restarting the host. Which I don't like doing as a problem resolution as you don't really know what the underlying problem is.

I also don't see an error log for node.

Any advice or guidance on how to determine what the problem is would be appreciated.

Comment: I was able to review the logs and see that there is a competing process for the port that the wiki is bound to.

Comment: I modified the port in the configuration. The server now starts error free. `pm2 show wiki` and `pm2 logs wiki` both look clean, however I still can't seem to get the page to load in my browser, it just spins.

Comment: OK, I found the problem. Last week I installed a server product for evaluation. That was the competing port. I modified the configurations appropriately and all is working again.